# Java Inferred Types and Lists: Working through general Quicksort example

Tags: java, list, quicksort, comparable, inferred-type

I am following along with [this example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quicksort#Java) of Quicksort implemented in Java, on Rosettacode. From what I understand this is supposed to take in an array of things that implement the Comparable interface, and that the type is inferred during runtime.   I wrapped this up in a little class with a main method, but get an slew of errors about the inferred type.  I am relative new to Java and not familiar with this construct yet.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class QuickSortExample {


    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> List<E> quickSort(List<E> arr) {
        if (arr.size() <= 1) return arr;
        E pivot = arr.getFirst();

        List<E> less = new LinkedList<E>();
        List<E> pivotList = new LinkedList<E>();
        List<E> more = new LinkedList<E>();

        for (E i: arr) {
            if (i.compareTo(pivot) < 0) less.add(i);
            else if (i.compareTo(pivot) > 0) more.add(i);
            else pivotList.add(i);
        }

        less = quickSort(less);
        more = quickSort(more);
        less.addAll(pivotList);
        less.addAll(more);
        return less;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] myArray = new int[]{2,3,1,6,2,87,5,3,546,9,2,3,8,111};
        int[] mySortedArray = quickSort(myArray);
        System.out.println(mySortedArray);
    }
}
```

And I get these errors on compile

```
 $ javac QuickSortExample.java
 QuickSortExample.java:11: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : method getFirst()
 location: interface java.util.List<E>
        E pivot = arr.getFirst();
                 ^
 QuickSortExample.java:37: <E>quickSort(java.util.List<E>) in QuickSortExample cannot be applied to (int[])
        int[] mySortedArray = quickSort(myArray);
                            ^
 2 errors
```

I have 3 questions.

1) What does the ? mean in the following statement?

```
<E extends Comparable<? super E>> List<E> quickSort(List<E> arr)
```

2)  It seems like this is made to work on LinkedList objects, due to the getFirst() method.  Is that correct?  If so, can I get this to work on a general List?  Would I have to cast my Array of ints as List.  I'm a little confused here.  I have been consulting both the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) javadocs.

3) Can I accomplish this all with the List object, instead of LinkedList?  Is there a reason LinkedList was chosen for this example that I dont understand?  Also, if I wanted to call this with an Array of Integers, would I have to cast(?) that input differently on the way in since it doesnt look like Array inherits from List?

Sorry for the really basic questions, just learning Java for real for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

1. The quick sort method accepts a `List` of objects of Type `X` and returns a `List` of type of `X`. Type `X` should implement the `Comparable` interface with generic type of `X`
2. You can use the method `Arrays.asList(<your-array>)` to convert the array to a list
3. There is no mention of `LinkedList` in the method contract, you can pass any type of `List` to the `quickSort` method and it will return an object of type `List`. `LinkedList` is an implementation of `List` used internally by the method.

Ex:

```
    Integer[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<Integer> asList = Arrays.asList(arr);
    quickSort(asList);
```

Comment: Great thanks, one more question, the method seems to need LinkedLists passed in because of the call to getFirst().  

`Davids-iMac:Java david$ javac QuickSort.java
QuickSort.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getFirst()
location: interface java.util.List<E>
        E pivot = arr.getFirst();
                     ^
1 error`
But if I try to cast asList as a LinkedList, I get an incompatible type error.  How should i think about reconciling this?  Is it possible in Java to make a general QuickSort that takes in anything that implements the List interface?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code in main method to the following one:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] arr = {2,3,1,6,2,87,5,3,546,9,2,3,8,111};
        List<Integer> asList = Arrays.asList(arr);
        List<Integer> mySortedArray = quickSort(asList);
        System.out.println(mySortedArray);
    }
```

the algorithm is perfectly working now.